# Android pocketsphinx & Fsg model

Tags: android, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx-android

## Context

I am currently building an sdk/service on wich applications can access to voice based command,
For the moment i'm using android pocketsphinx to detect a keyword (which is "wake"), and then analyse whole sentence with google voice recognition,
But my problem is i want to make it all offline! So i'm in my way to replace google voice recognition by a full utilisation of pocketsphinx...

## My Problem

The user define which is the word he want to detect, and previously i just compared the said-word and what google voice speech-to-text returned me...
So know I want to update the grammar that pocket sphinx use with just the word given by the user, which problematic because (following the javadoc of android pocket sphinx) it can only take grammar files!

## Question

Are there any way i can update android pocketsphinx grammar on the fly?

## Edit

I forgot to talk about this method:
`public void addFsgSearch(String searchName, FsgModel fsgModel)` (in [github pocketsphinx](https://github.com/cesine/AndroidPocketSphinx/blob/master/src/edu/cmu/pocketsphinx/SpeechRecognizer.java))

wich seem to deosn't take a grammar file like any other grammar setter method, but rather a class/struct? but the problem it's it isn't documented.....

Answer (score 0):

If you need to detect just one word, consider using `addKeywordSearch`.

Comment: I wont add just one, but a number (superior to one) that i don't know

Comment: I meant a phrase, not a word. Like `addKeyWordSearch("keyword", "okay google")`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and more. Perhaps these undocumented discoveries can help you.

Using the overloaded method "addGrammarSearch(String name, String fsgString)" allows you to put your entire FSG or JSGF grammar definition in a string, rather than sourcing it from a file if you wish (only a small file open/read time advantage).

"addKeyphraseSearch(String name, String keyphrase)" // only accommodates ONE WORD or PHRASE, no threshold, no grammar.

"addKeywordSearch(String name, File keywordList)" // accommodates MULTIPLE key WORDS or PHRASES, adding thresholds for each.

Several caveats include:

1. The grammar searches use JSGF format, parsing the defined syntax correctly.  However:
   1.1 Tags are not implemented
   1.2 Unclear if weights (though the same // syntax as in keyword lists) actually apply recognizer thresholds (they have different meanings in PocketSphinx versus Sun Microsystems).
   1.3 Rule names are also not implemented either.
   1.4 In other words, you provide a grammar in JSGF, and your Hypothesis as well as FinalResult strings still give you the recognized lowest-level phrase detected in the grammar -- NOT the grammar tags, nor even rule metasymbols.
   1.3.1  IMHO, that makes grammars pointless, and actually less efficient and less flexible than keyword list files (which are actually words or phrases) due to the option to provide a threshold for recognizer scrutiny, per phrase.  Further, if the RULE & TAG names are not returned, then there is zero information regarding the structure of the grammar that was recognized.  So as syntactically complex and flexible as it is, I do not see the advantage of bothering with a grammar definition at all in PocketSphinx; the best multiple keyphrase approach is simply to expand your grammar into a keyword list file.  Please correct me if I am mistaken.
2. Search methods, whether containing the word "phrase"  or the word "word", actually accommodate both phrases or single words.
3. I have assumptions re: the undocumented fsgModel class, but we're not allowed to give assumptions.

Though this may help clarify some aspects,the above fails to add any functionality to the package.  Lastly, the C source code has methods getRuleName() and getTagName().  But, discussions regarding this topic between users and developers seems to stonewall -- their is no motivation to add tags or rule name associations to recognized words or phrases in a defined grammar, apparently because the developers believe grammars are old-school and nobody uses them anymore.